# Obtain co-ordinates of an HTML5 canvas on a page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a a canvas inside another canvas.

```
  <canvas id ='canvas2' height="718" width="1316"></canvas>
```

its css is something

```
#canvas2{
position:absolute;
width :95%;
height:90%;
top:5%;
left:2.5%;
background: #ffff56;
cursor:pointer;

}
```

next I have drawn some rectangles on it. I need to colour those with mouse click. I used an action listener.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);
var $canvas = $("#canvas2");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
function doMouseDown(event){
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
 var x= parseInt(event.clientX - offsetX);
 var y = parseInt(event.clientY - offsetY);
}
```

But this is not the right way I know as I am getting all the wrong canvas co-ordinates on x and y.
Can someone show the right way?

Comment: What co-ordinates are you expecting when you click on topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft and bottomRight corners of the canvas ?

Comment: (0,0), (1316,0), (0,718),(1316,718)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has your canvas been scrolled?

If yes, then you also need to account for the distance the canvas has been scrolled in the browser.

You might check out canvas.getBoundingClientRect() as a way to get the canvas position with the scrolling accounted for:

```
function handleMousemove(e){

     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();

     // if the canvas is stationary (not scrolling) then you can do
     // .getBoundingClientRect once at the start of the app

     var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

     // calc mouse position based on the bounding box

     var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-BB.left);
     var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-BB.top);

     console.log(mouseX+"/"+mouseY);

}
```